# cant find whos the owner of malloc - memory leak

Tags: c

I have a problem with a memory leak with `temp_line`.

This function read a whole text from a file and assign each word to a big linked list. I cant figure out who's the owner of `temp_line` whenever I exit this function, and whenever I am trying to replace `temp_line` with non-dynamic variable (like `temp_line[1000]`) every time I get a new line, its overwritten the data from the old line (and then I am getting a segmentation fault because of that).

So I really don't know how to solve it.

```
int fill(FILE *f, LinkedList *linkedlist) {
    FILE *file = fopen((const char *)f, "r");
    char line[MAX_LINE];   //MAX_LINE = 1000
    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE, file) != NULL) {
        char *temp_line = malloc(MAX_LINE);
        if (temp_line == NULL) {
            fclose(file);
            return false;
        }
        strcpy(temp_line, line);
        read_line(linkedlist, temp_line);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}

int read_line(LinkedList *linkedlist, char *line) {
    char *word;
    while (true) {
        word = strtok(NULL, "\n ");
        if (word == NULL) {
            break;
        }
        add_node(linkedlist, word);
    }
    return true;
}
```

`add_node` adds the node to the linked list and returns the node.

Comment: Your MCV example is not complete but I can see that you are not using `strtok` correctly. Google `man strtok`.

Comment: It looks like you might be able to call `free(temp_line);` after `read_line (linkedlist, temp_line);`, but that depends on whether `add_node(linkedlist, word);` creates a copy of `word` or not. If not, you need to keep track of all `temp_line` memory locations and free them at the end of your program.

Comment: You should post the code for `add_node()` and `del_node()` and the `main()` function

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- `FILE *file = fopen((const char *)f, "r");` with `f` defined as `FILE *f` is probably incorrect. If you are given a `FILE *`, just read from it.
- `strtok` should be first called with the string, then with `NULL` until it returns `NULL`.
- you insert nodes into the list from pointers into the middle of the block allocated by `read_line`. There is no way to determine the beginning of such a block, nor any way to determine how many pointers point into the block. Memory allocated and used this way cannot be freed. You should instead use `strdup()` to allocate individual copies of the words. These pointers can be later freed with `free()` in the `del_node()` function.  Alternately, `add_node()` could make a copy of the string argument, which would be consistent with `del_node()` freeing this data.
- regarding your question: *Cannot find who is the owner of a malloc block*... indeed it is the C programmers' responsibility to keep track of allocated memory. There is no way to test if a pointer is valid, not whether it points to an allocated block. You must design the program consistently so memory ownership can always be determined from context.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int read_line(LinkedList *linkedlist, char *line) {
    char *word;
    while ((word = strtok(line, "\n ")) != NULL) {
        add_node(linkedlist, strdup(word));
        line = NULL;
    }
    return true;
}

int fill(FILE *file, LinkedList *linkedlist) {
    char line[MAX_LINE];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) {
        read_line(linkedlist, line);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You may want to explain why using `strdup` this way makes it a whole lot easier to write `add_node`. And I'll bet you the real problem is the OP doesn't know how to write `del_node` given how he was using `malloc` and `strcpy` (effectively `strdup`).

Comment: @JeffHolt: you have a good point! This is a typical XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to replace temp_line with non-dynamic variable (like temp_line[1000])

`temp_line[1000]` is also called ["automatic memory"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) because it is automatically deallocated at the end of its scope. What this means is `temp_line` would be deallocated on each iteration of the loop.

Perhaps the important thing to realize is `strtok` *does not allocate any memory*. `word` points at memory inside `temp_line`.

Let's say you did.

```
while (fgets (line, MAX_LINE, file) != NULL) {
  char temp_line[MAX_LINE];
  strcpy(temp_line, line);
  read_line(linkedlist, temp_line);
}
```

On each loop `temp_line` will be allocated, passed into `read_line`, and then deallocated. The words you add to the linked list point at deallocated memory.

The question is who "owns" memory. Because it uses `strtok`, `read_line` assumes that it owns `line` and that `line` will not be deallocated. The safe thing to do is to change `read_line` so it copies each `word` from `line`.

```
int read_line(LinkedList *linkedlist, char *line) {
    for(
      char *word = strtok(line, "\n ");
      word;
      word = strtok(NULL, "\n ")
    ) {
        // Duplicate the word so it no longer refers to line.
        add_node(linkedlist, strdup(word));
    }
    return true;
}
```